# Merging "the lawn is trampled on" & "the lawn is sparse/scattered/..."

Tags: word-choice, past-participles

Let's start with the skeleton sentence:

> I looked at the lawn of the playground.

People trample on the lawn of the playground, so it becomes sparse/scattered/...

Q1: Which word should I use to express that the lawn is missing/trampled down: sparse/scattered/...?

Q2: How should I use the verb "trample" and the word from Q1 in the skeleton sentence, e.g. based on the expression "trample to death", I would generate this, but doesn't sound correct to me:

> I looked at the trampled to sparse/scattered/... lawn of the playground.

Comment: You can describe a lawn as _sparse_, but _the scattered lawn_ sounds very odd. If the whole playground is like that, I would call it 'the grass of the playground' (a lawn is a grassy area in a larger garden), and if the grass is sparse, you can leave it to the reader to work out that it has been worn away by trampling.

Comment: *Lawn of the playground* doesn't really make sense.  When I (an American English speaker) hear *lawn*, I think of something like [this](https://empire-s3-production.bobvila.com/slides/8978/original/Planting_Trees_in_Front_Yard.jpg?1555630374).  Playgrounds might have grassy areas, but we wouldn't call it a *lawn*.

Comment: I looked at the grass at the playground.

Comment: trample is not right here. Grass in playground field is meant to be walked on. Trample has negative connotations with the idea of flattening; She trampled on the floor beds. We normally don't say that grass is trampled on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not "sparse" or "scattered".  The word to use is "worn". It is an adjective.

There are lots of other words that are also possible: "tired", "unhealthy", "damaged", "sad". If your lawn is worn, it will have bare patches.

Now there is an idiom "... to death".  But note that "death" is a noun, so "to sparse" or "to worn" doesn't work.

There are lots of ways you could talk about the lawn:

> I looked at the trampled and worn-out lawn of the playground, which had bare patches where people had been playing on it.

Comment: Based on the comments, I use "grass" then, and "worn[-out]" also by your answer. But is there really no way to use "trample" & "worn" to express consequence, i.e. the latter follows from the former? Or does the "and" in your example "trampled and worn-out" express consequence? What about a comma: "trampled, worn-out"?

Comment: Yes, you would understand that trampling caused the lawn to wear out.

Comment: I don't like trampled much here. After all, grass can be walked on quite heavily and not become thinned out. Don't trample on the flower beds. Okay, but not the lawn.

Comment: @Lambie I think when children (and perhaps their parents as well) play different sorts of things at the playground, they are not like when they ordinarily walk, that is why I chose this word. Regarding your comment below the question, it is the intention to have negative connotation - or is it too strong?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Yes, children may run around on the grass, but we would not say trampled on it. Trampled, like I said, implies that something is sticking up out of the ground and is being crushed. The children trampled on all the flowers along the pathway.

Comment: I don't know... some people are pretty protective of their turf, and would certainly describe *children running about* as trampling.    See [Asterix in Britain](https://comicsagogo.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/asterix-in-britain-003.jpg)

Comment: @Lambie JamesK 
[The Guardian's article](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/gardening-blog/2015/may/08/how-do-i-revive-my-trampled-lawn
) is probably a better example that it is linguistically valid to say it - it is another question, if it is valid lawn lingo or not. But in general, the speaker can say illogical things as well, correcting all these with rigor is overkill.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/trample **to step heavily on something or someone, causing damage or injury:
Somebody trampled all over my flowerbeds!
Eight people were trampled to death (= killed) when the stadium collapsed and the crowd rushed out onto the field.** The Guardian article implies damage to grass but it is not the best choice of word.

Comment: @JamesK Hi! I upvoted your good answer! Your good answer does not deserve a downvote!

Answer (score 1):

bare spots in the lawn
thin spots in the lawn
bare patches in the lawn
thinned grass or thinned turf

I looked at the **thin turf** or **patchy turf** at the playground.

We normally would not say that a lawn is trampled. Dogs are known to trample flower beds, yes. Grass at playgrounds is meant to be walked on. Trample (outside) is for things that stick up from the ground like plants or flowers and are thereby **flattened**.

[lawn lingo](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/thin-lawn-thicker-21951.html)